# How to export a conda package with all its dependencies and install it on another computer with no Internet connection?

Tags: pip, anaconda

conda offers an easy way to pack an entire environment and transfer it to another server. But recently I am trying to install a spacy model using the wheel file. But it seems that it still need internet connection to download the dependencies. Any easier way for doing this, like installing it on my personal computer first and export it with all its dependencies, so that I can install it on my server which has no Internet connection.